# Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Hi at all i need to find a solution for Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR here is my code and my json string.

```
<?
      include"db.inc.php";//database connection
      $order = "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta";
      $result = mysql_query($order);
      $array = array();
      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      if($row[meta_id]>=557 && $row[meta_key]=='gdlr-soccer-player-settings'){
            $temp_ar = json_decode($row[meta_value],true);
            array_push($array,$temp_ar);
        }

        }
      /*$count = count($array);
      for($i = 0;$i<$count;$i++){
        echo $array[$i];
        echo "<div></div>";

        }*/
        print_r($array->player-info->first-name);
        ?>
```

and json

```
{"player-info":{"first-name":"Antonio","last-name":"Russo","squad":"","position":"Portiere","position-ab":"","nationality":"","date-of-birth":"","height":"","weight":"","games-played":"","minutes-played":"","starts":"","substitution-on":"","substitution-off":"","facebook":"","twitter":"","youtube":"","instagram":""},"player-stats":{"passes":"","passing-accuracy":"","passing-accuracy-opp":"","duels-won":"","duels-lost":"","duels-won-percent":"","aerial-duels-won":"","aerial-duels-lost":"","aerial-duels-won-percent":"","recoveries":"","tackles-won":"","tackles-lost":"","tackles-won-percent":"","clearances":"","blocks":"","interceptions":"","penalties-conceded":"","fouls-won":"","fouls-conceded":"","yellow-cards":"","red-cards":"","goals":"","penalty-goals":"","minutes-per-goal":"","total-shots-on-target":"","total-shots-off-target":"","shooting-accuracy":"","successful-crosses":"","unsuccessful-crosses":"","successful-crosses-percent":"","assists":"","chances-created":"","penalties-won":"","offsides":""},"biography":{"biography":""},"gallery":{"player-gallery":""}}
```

Update here the structure

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Antonio [last-name] => Russo [squad] => [position] => Portiere [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [1] => [2] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Domenico [last-name] => Galluccio [squad] => [position] => Portiere [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [3] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Carmelo [last-name] => Contro [squad] => [position] => Difensore [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [4] => [5] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Michelangelo [last-name] => Ierace [squad] => [position] => Difensore [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [6] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Raffaele [last-name] => Maurici [squad] => [position] => Difensore [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [7] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Serafino [last-name] => Mamone [squad] => [position] => Difensore [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [8] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Vincenzo [last-name] => Startari [squad] => [position] => Difensore [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [9] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Gabriele [last-name] => Guerrisi [squad] => [position] => Laterale [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [10] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Giovanni [last-name] => Nava [squad] => [position] => Laterale [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [11] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Mario [last-name] => Foti [squad] => [position] => Laterale [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [12] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Michele [last-name] => Abramo [squad] => [position] => Laterale [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [13] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Pasquale [last-name] => Zappia [squad] => [position] => Laterale [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [14] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Valentino [last-name] => Tassone [squad] => [position] => Laterale [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [15] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Antonio [last-name] => Sorrenti [squad] => [position] => Attaccante [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [16] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Claudio [last-name] => Monterosso [squad] => [position] => Attaccante [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [17] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Domenico [last-name] => Cosoleto [squad] => [position] => Attaccante [position-ab] => [nationality] => [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [goals] => 50 [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) [18] => Array ( [player-info] => Array ( [first-name] => Peppe [last-name] => ZAPPIA [squad] => [position] => COGLIONE [position-ab] => [goals] => [penalty-goals] => [minutes-per-goal] => [total-shots-on-target] => [nationality] => AFRICANO [date-of-birth] => [height] => [weight] => [games-played] => [minutes-played] => [starts] => [substitution-on] => [substitution-off] => [facebook] => [twitter] => [youtube] => [instagram] => ) [player-stats] => Array ( [passes] => [passing-accuracy] => [passing-accuracy-opp] => [duels-won] => [duels-lost] => [duels-won-percent] => [aerial-duels-won] => [aerial-duels-lost] => [aerial-duels-won-percent] => [recoveries] => [tackles-won] => [tackles-lost] => [tackles-won-percent] => [clearances] => [blocks] => [interceptions] => [penalties-conceded] => [fouls-won] => [fouls-conceded] => [yellow-cards] => [red-cards] => [total-shots-off-target] => [shooting-accuracy] => [successful-crosses] => [unsuccessful-crosses] => [successful-crosses-percent] => [assists] => [chances-created] => [penalties-won] => [offsides] => ) [biography] => Array ( [biography] => ) [gallery] => Array ( [player-gallery] => ) ) )
```

any idea thanks at all!

Here the solution!

```
$array[0]['player-info']['first-name']
```

Comment: `array_push()` What do you thing this does? Definitely not creating an object!

Comment: Missing quotes in your `while`'d columns.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).

Comment: put elemen into array

Comment: @GiuseppeZappia *put elemen into array* 100 points! `->` And does this access an array element or an object property (BTW: The variable name gives you a hint)? Do a `print_r($array)` and post the structure here

Comment: @Rizier123 really i don't know

Comment: @GiuseppeZappia Do you see it now, what I meant?! (BTW: Please don't write an answer in your question; If you figured it out yourself add answer, you can answer your own question)

Answer (score 0):

Add proper quotes to your array identifiers in the `while` loop. Change this:

```
if($row[meta_id]>=557 && $row[meta_key]=='gdlr-soccer-player-settings'){
   $temp_ar = json_decode($row[meta_value],true);
   array_push($array,$temp_ar);
}
```

to this:

```
if($row['meta_id'] >=557 && $row['meta_key']=='gdlr-soccer-player-settings'){
   $temp_ar = json_decode($row['meta_value'],true);
   array_push($array,$temp_ar);
}
```

Also change the following statement:

```
print_r($array->player-info->first-name);
```

to:

```
print_r($array['player-info']['first-name']); // since you're working with an array, not an object
```

Comment: I'd help out but Cajun sausage on the grill. ciao for niao

Comment: Just do `print_r($array);` and edit your original post with the results. My guess is that your `if` conditions are *never* met. What are in the columns `meta_id` and `meta_key`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard The OP posted an answer in the same page here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29357165/ then posted it as a question http://stackoverflow.com/q/29357624/ - ouatte de phoque?

Comment: It was deleted Sam @JayBlanchard

Comment: I see that @Fred-ii- *Mornin' Ralph*

Comment: *Mornin' Sam* - @JayBlanchard Slow morning today, ever since they added that Egg thing. Takes forever for pages to load and message notification; what gives? lol

Comment: I know! It kinda' stinks. I'll pop over to *Meta* and see what the feedback is.